# How to store data in map with dynamic input in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, dictionary, dynamic

I'm buliding my first projetct with node.js and trying to store user's input with Map
here's my code and 2 incoming input:

```
const command = new Map()

let commadParam = ['userAccount', 'john'] // <- first input then it should be store for later use

let account = 'userAccount-'+ commadParam[1]
consolo.log(account) // 'userAccount-john'

commadParam = ['charItem','BowJohn'] // <- simulate second input

let char = 'charItem-' + commadParam[1]
consolo.log(char) // 'charItem-BowJohn'

command.set(account, account.split('-')[1])
command.set(char, char.split('-')[1])

console.log(command)// Map{'userAccount-john' => 'john', 'charItem-BowJohn' => 'BowJohn'}
```

it works fine when i literly put 2 input like example, but when i ran my app and type first input then after like 1sec i type second input it overwrite the first map

how do i store first input with Map for later use (like 1-3sec later) or should i just use DB for storing(like redis)?
Thanks!

Here is full code:

```
const replyMsg = async (reqBody, res) => {
    const reqBodyMsg = reqBody.events[0].type
    const command = new Map()

    if (reqBodyMsg === 'message') {
       
        let commandParam = reqBody.events[0].message.text.split(' ')

        let account = 'userAccount-' + commandParam[1]
        let char = 'charItem-' + commandParam[1]

        command.set(account, account.split('-')[1])
        command.set(char, char.split('-')[1])
  
        let accountName = command.get(account)
        let charName = command.get(char)

        //input user account for character list
        if (commandParam[0] === 'userAccount') {

            const dataString = await getChar(reqBody, res, accountName)

            console.log(dataString)
        }

        //input character name to get character equipment
        if (commandParam[0] === 'charItem') {
            // accountName = data.key[1]
            // console.log(commandParam[0])
            // const charName = commandParam[1]

            const dataString = await getItem(reqBody, res, accountName, charName)
            console.log(dataString)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you're doing `command = new Map()` after every input. You should only do that once.

Comment: If that's not what you're doing, you need to post a [mre]

Comment: @Barmar hi how do i only dot command = new Map() once? i dont get it, i think i need to figure ouy how to post  minimal reproducible example

Comment: You do it at the beginning of the script, not inside whatever function runs whenever the user inputs data.

Comment: @Barmar i tried to put it outside of the function, it start store my first input, but after second input it overwrite again like before

Answer (score 0):

Declare and initialize `command` outside the function. Then if `commandParam[1]` is different it should not overwrite the old values in the map.

I'm not sure why you need `accountName` and `charName`, they should be the same as `commandParam[1]`.

```js
const command = new Map()

const replyMsg = async(reqBody, res) => {
  const reqBodyMsg = reqBody.events[0].type

  if (reqBodyMsg === 'message') {

    let commandParam = reqBody.events[0].message.text.split(' ')

    let account = 'userAccount-' + commandParam[1]
    let char = 'charItem-' + commandParam[1]

    command.set(account, account.split('-')[1])
    command.set(char, char.split('-')[1])

    let accountName = command.get(account)
    let charName = command.get(char)

    //input user account for character list
    if (commandParam[0] === 'userAccount') {

      const dataString = await getChar(reqBody, res, accountName)

      console.log(dataString)
    }

    //input character name to get character equipment
    if (commandParam[0] === 'charItem') {
      // accountName = data.key[1]
      // console.log(commandParam[0])
      // const charName = commandParam[1]

      const dataString = await getItem(reqBody, res, accountName, charName)
      console.log(dataString)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: commandParam[0] and commandParam[1] are both different in 2 input first input is ['userAccount', 'john'] ,then second one is ['charItem','BowJohn'] they all different.
i need to declare accountName and charName for augment for getChar and getItem.

Comment: So the first input should create map entries `userAccount-John => John` and `charItem-John => John`. The second input will create `userAccount-BowJohn => BowJohn` and `charItem-BowJohn => BowJohn`.

Comment: pretty much like you said my first input only create `userAccount-John => John` then second input create `userAccount-John => John` + `userAccount-BowJohn => BowJohn ` and `charItem-BowJohn => BowJohn`

Comment: I find out where i mass up, i declare accountName in front of all `if statement`  then move `command.set(char)` into second `if statement`,after second input i use `for loop +.entries()` and redeclare accountName to comman's value,and everything worked as i image!! Thank you!